# MqttAndroidClient - onFailure

Tags: android, android-asynctask, mqtt, paho

#Question#
Why I am able to connect to my server over my mainActivity, but not over a fragment?

#Setup#
##Program 1 - works...##
Right now, I have two programs.
The first one is called **mqtt_test** which includes a MainActivity, a Button and the connection-class Mqtt. So there are **no** fragments.

With that program I am able to connect to my Server, subscribe and receive messages.

###Code of first program###

```
public class mqtt {
private Context context;
private String broker = "tcp://10.34.5.134:1883";
private String clientId= "DefaultName";
private MqttAndroidClient client;
private ConnectionListener connectionListener;

private static final String TAG_MQTT= "MQTT";

public mqtt(Context context)
{
    this.context = context;
}
public void connect()
{
    final String clientId = MqttClient.generateClientId();

    //set options
    MqttConnectOptions options = new MqttConnectOptions();
    options.setMqttVersion(MqttConnectOptions.MQTT_VERSION_3_1);

    client =
            new MqttAndroidClient(context, broker,
                    clientId);

    try {
        IMqttToken token = client.connect(options);
        token.setActionCallback(new IMqttActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                // We are connected
                Log.d(TAG_MQTT, "onSuccess");
                connectionListener.connected(true);
                client.setCallback(new MqttCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void connectionLost(Throwable cause) {
                        Log.d(TAG_MQTT, "connectionLost: ");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage message) throws Exception {
                        Log.d(TAG_MQTT, "messageArrived: Message: " + message.toString() + " with topic: " + topic);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken token) {
                        Log.d(TAG_MQTT, "deliveryComplete: ");
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
                // Something went wrong e.g. connection timeout or firewall problems
                Log.d(TAG_MQTT, "onFailure");
                connectionListener.connected(false);

            }
        });
    } catch (MqttException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void subscribe(final String topic, int qos)
{
    if(client.isConnected())
    {
        try {
            IMqttToken subToken = client.subscribe(topic, qos);
            subToken.setActionCallback(new IMqttActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                    // The message was published
                    Log.d(TAG_MQTT, "onSuccess: Subscripted with topic: " + topic);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken,
                                      Throwable exception) {
                    // The subscription could not be performed, maybe the user was not
                    // authorized to subscribe on the specified topic e.g. using wildcards
                    Log.d(TAG_MQTT, "onFailure: The subscription failed");
                }
            });
        } catch (MqttException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
    public void publish(String topic, String payload, int qos)
    {

        byte[] encodedPayload = new byte[0];
        try {
            encodedPayload = payload.getBytes("UTF-8");
            MqttMessage message = new MqttMessage(encodedPayload);
            client.publish(topic, message);
            Log.d(TAG_MQTT, "publish: Published message:" + payload + " to topic: " + topic);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | MqttException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d(TAG_MQTT, "publish: Error");
        }
    }

    public void setConnectionListener(ConnectionListener connectionListener) {
        this.connectionListener = connectionListener;
    }
}
```

### Program 2 - doesn't work##

In my second program I am using nearly the same code. However, I am using fragments for future business. In some fragments are buttons, which are calling the right method.
If I press the button, then the right method gets called, like in the first program.
But the program jumps over the async task. OnSuccess or onFailure never gets called.

```
IMqttToken token = client.connect(null, new IMqttActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                    // connected
                    Log.d(TAG_CONNECTION, "onSuccess");
                    connectionListener.connected(true);
                    client.setCallback(new MqttCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void connectionLost(Throwable cause) {
                            Log.d(TAG_CONNECTION, "connectionLost: ");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage message) throws Exception {
                            Log.d(TAG_CONNECTION, "messageArrived: Message: " + message.toString() + " with topic: " + topic);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken token) {
                            Log.d(TAG_CONNECTION, "deliveryComplete: ");
                        }
                    });
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
                    Log.d(TAG_CONNECTION, "onFailure");
                    connectionListener.connected(false);
                    Log.d(TAG_CONNECTION, exception.getMessage());

                }
            });
```

Then I called the connect-method over a new thread:

```
@Override
    public void doSmth() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // a potentially  time consuming task
                mqttConnection.connect();
            }
        }).start();

    }
```

Finally I got an answer:
`D/CONNECTION: cannot start service org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttService`

I don't understand why this doesn't work. Maybe you have some input.

To be clear: Both programs do have the same permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

#Assumption#
I think, I have to use more asycTasks to solve this problem.

#Input/links#
It would be awesome, if you could share some links. In the best case with some examples. I only found examples which are running in a single MainActivity.

Answer (score 0):

The error

```
D/CONNECTION: cannot start service org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttService
```

possibly indicates that the entry

```
<service android:name="org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttService">
</service>
```

in AndroidManifest.xml is missing